# magento zend _pdf error

Tags: magento, zend-framework

Fatal error: Declaration of Zend_Pdf_FileParserDataSource_File::__construct() must be compatible with Zend_Pdf_FileParserDataSource::__construct()

My php version is 5.4

I need to know if I upgrade my php version to 5.5.this error will get solved or not?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about this error, but perhaps you are passing some parameter in  __construct() function in your magento module function and parent abstract class doesn't accept any parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading PHP won't fix it. This is a [bug in Zend Framework that was fixed in version 1.12](http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-12093). I don't use Magento but as far as I can tell it ships with version 1.11.1 (which is around three years old).

Until Magento updates, your best option is probably to apply the fix to the copy of ZF in your Magento installation. All you need to do is comment out the constructor in `lib/Zend/Pdf/FileParserDataSource.php`, which is this line: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/master/lib/Zend/Pdf/FileParserDataSource.php#L78. You will have to re-apply this fix everytime you update Magento.

Comment: I have commented the abstract public function __construct() but it is giving another error

Comment: Invalid method Mage_Core_Block_Template::toPdf(Array
(
)
)

#0 /usr/www/users/stagepegrq/app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Block/Info.php(92): Varien_Object->__call('toPdf', Array)
#1 /usr/www/users/stagepegrq/app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Block/Info.php(92): Mage_Core_Block_Template->toPdf()
#2 /usr/www/users/stagepegrq/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/payment/info/pdf/default.phtml(40): Mage_Payment_Block_Info->getChildPdfAsArray()